# Trying to pull a text string from block of HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to pull a text string (an article title) from a piece of HTML. In this case, it's "Journalist Allegedly Spied on Zoom Meetings of Rivals in Hilariously Dumb Ways."

The problem is, the title doesn't have any identifiers I can see. It's in a few places in the HTML, but the divs it's in don't have stable names.

I tried:

```
var url = $(uCW).find('[href^="https://l.facebook"]').text();
```

But get the wrong chunk of text. (uCW is the variable name I gave to the div this is all in — it works fine for grabbing other information here). Really, I'm having trouble figuring out how to select it — in theory I could specify the exact children everything is in, but the children change a lot and I'd like to use a more stable method.

```
<div class="_1dwg _1w_m _q7o" data-vc-ignore-dynamic="1">
   <div></div>
   <div class="_4r_y">
      <div class="_6a uiPopover _5pbi _cmw _b1e _1wbl" id="u_fetchstream_4_6"><a aria-label="Story options" data-testid="post_chevron_button" class="_4xev _p" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" rel="toggle" href="#" role="button" id="u_fetchstream_4_7"></a></div>
   </div>
   <div>
      <div class="v_zhq0t5rr6 _5eit p_zhq0tbcbb clearfix">
         <div class="clearfix c_zhq0t5thj">
            <a target="" class="_5pb8 u_zhq0tbcb8 _8o _8s lfloat _ohe" title="Person" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" data-ft="{"tn":"m"}" href="https://www.facebook.com/j.newsham?fref=nf&__tn__=%2Cdm-R-R&eid=ARBC4Tpii73ko-nTTzvjgbhv8Uvq1GIHitUe_IHE0Ksi1su-LTuENPi9GCWskRJMLwp4VMol7R2filWQ" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/user.php?id=675172323&extragetparams=%7B%22__tn__%22%3A%22%2Cdm-R-R%22%2C%22eid%22%3A%22ARBC4Tpii73ko-nTTzvjgbhv8Uvq1GIHitUe_IHE0Ksi1su-LTuENPi9GCWskRJMLwp4VMol7R2filWQ%22%7D" data-hovercard-prefer-more-content-show="1">
               <div class="_38vo">
                  <!-- react-mount-point-unstable -->
                  <div><img class="_s0 _4ooo _5xib _5sq7 _44ma _rw img" src="https://scontent-ort2-2.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p112x112/38427941_10156325214622324_8412493305270501376_n.jpg?_nc_cat=110&_nc_sid=dbb9e7&_nc_ohc=e5WgZHVuabcAX-4npCK&_nc_ht=scontent-ort2-2.xx&_nc_tp=6&oh=eb95679d9ee7fb5be65b6bdb23dcf7b2&oe=5ECE2ADB" alt="" aria-label="Person" role="img"></div>
               </div>
            </a>
            <div class="clearfix _42ef">
               <div class="rfloat _ohf"></div>
               <div class="l_zhq0t5thg">
                  <div>
                     <div class="_6a _5u5j">
                        <div class="_6a _6b" style="height:40px"></div>
                        <div class="_6a _5u5j _6b">
                           <h5 class="_7tae _14f3 _14f5 _5pbw _5vra" data-ft="{"tn":"C"}" id="js_9e"><span class="fwn fcg"><span class="fwb fcg" data-ft="{"tn":";"}"><a title="Person" href="https://www.facebook.com/j.newsham?__tn__=%2CdC-R-R&eid=ARBQdCphQpNyE52IVRqnH7bi35xke_7h8ucoRhm-SykkuyeLTHQwdjplzLmwjPJI_2_SlLcyDWm9pGoB&hc_ref=ARRHpOlTgvosbrodRaKBuoiUQmaEP0kbw6SoEqUpbxJ-qgG56wADKG8zO652g3vacIc&fref=nf" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/user.php?id=675172323&extragetparams=%7B%22__tn__%22%3A%22%2CdC-R-R%22%2C%22eid%22%3A%22ARBQdCphQpNyE52IVRqnH7bi35xke_7h8ucoRhm-SykkuyeLTHQwdjplzLmwjPJI_2_SlLcyDWm9pGoB%22%2C%22hc_ref%22%3A%22ARRHpOlTgvosbrodRaKBuoiUQmaEP0kbw6SoEqUpbxJ-qgG56wADKG8zO652g3vacIc%22%2C%22fref%22%3A%22nf%22%7D" data-hovercard-prefer-more-content-show="1" data-hovercard-referer="ARRHpOlTgvosbrodRaKBuoiUQmaEP0kbw6SoEqUpbxJ-qgG56wADKG8zO652g3vacIc">Person</a></span></span></h5>
                           <div class="_5pcp _5lel _2jyu _232_" id="feed_subtitle_675172323:7304407797214710582" data-testid="story-subtitle">
                              <span class="z_zhq0t6o5b"><span class="fsm fwn fcg"><a class="_5pcq" href="/j.newsham/posts/10157963951497324" target=""><abbr data-utime="1588120184" title="Tuesday, April 28, 2020 at 7:29 PM" data-shorten="1" class="_5ptz timestamp livetimestamp"><span class="timestampContent" id="js_9f">16 hrs</span></abbr></a></span></span><span class="_6spk" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true"> · </span>
                              <div class="_6a _29ee _4f-9 _43_1" data-hover="tooltip" data-tooltip-content="Shared with: Person's friends" role="img" aria-label="Shared with: Person's friends"><span><i class="_1lbg img sp_Ke6ZUJH-N4S_1_5x sx_73b6dc"></i></span></div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="userContent"></div>
      <div class="_3x-2" data-ft="{"tn":"H"}">
         <div data-ft="{"tn":"H"}">
            <div class="mtm">
               <div id="u_fetchstream_4_1" class="_6m2 _1zpr clearfix _dcs _4_w4 _41u- _59ap _2bf7 _64lx _3eqz _20pq _3eqw _2rk1 _359m _3n1j _5qqr" data-ft="{"tn":"H"}">
                  <div class="clearfix _2r3x">
                     <div class="lfloat _ohe">
                        <span class="_3m6-">
                           <div class="_63yw">
                              <div class="_6ks">
                                 <a href="https://gizmodo.com/journalist-allegedly-spied-on-zoom-meetings-of-rivals-i-1843125262?utm_campaign=Gizmodo&utm_content&utm_medium=SocialMarketing&utm_source=facebook&fbclid=IwAR3MOk2OqjX3z6DNKgdmlVDtcYQz4xIx-CRsQOuV39hVGZR_U-TjgqTKSHQ" aria-describedby="u_fetchstream_4_3" aria-label="Journalist Allegedly Spied on Zoom Meetings of Rivals in Hilariously Dumb Ways" tabindex="-1" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow" data-lynx-mode="asynclazy" data-lynx-uri="https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fgizmodo.com%2Fjournalist-allegedly-spied-on-zoom-meetings-of-rivals-i-1843125262%3Futm_campaign%3DGizmodo%26utm_content%26utm_medium%3DSocialMarketing%26utm_source%3Dfacebook%26fbclid%3DIwAR3MOk2OqjX3z6DNKgdmlVDtcYQz4xIx-CRsQOuV39hVGZR_U-TjgqTKSHQ&h=AT0v6E7lQPPlUT-t8yQbu0DBEukuzdXli3s4pdRZxCF9EVtUE0omFYcc-fOtFYQJIHWOVgDfrGhVsH4T3uqimv560qNSBhRnwdM_iCwl4BQJ1f9r5rrk9K1zibH3nA9ZhUT6-YdcIkm7lBZtJYn6SKbWmmPzJsBUI-LcjNoQHXw">
                                    <div class="accessible_elem inlineBlock" id="u_fetchstream_4_3">Financial Times reporter Mark Di Stefano allegedly spied on Zoom meetings at rival newspapers the Independent and the Evening Standard to get scoops on staff cuts and furloughs due to the coronavirus pandemic, according to a report from the UK’s Independent. And he did a comically bad job of cover...</div>
                                    <div class="_6l- __c_">
                                       <div class="uiScaledImageContainer _6m5 fbStoryAttachmentImage" style="width:514px;height:268.42222222222px;"><img class="scaledImageFitWidth img" src="https://external-ort2-2.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQCX1CnigNk3SZXL&w=540&h=282&url=https%3A%2F%2Fi.kinja-img.com%2Fgawker-media%2Fimage%2Fupload%2Fc_fill%2Cf_auto%2Cfl_progressive%2Cg_center%2Ch_675%2Cpg_1%2Cq_80%2Cw_1200%2Fy3dmfzz6ktqefakczlow.jpg&cfs=1&upscale=1&fallback=news_d_placeholder_publisher&_nc_hash=AQAApLwXk6n73twX" data-src="https://external-ort2-2.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQCX1CnigNk3SZXL&w=540&h=282&url=https%3A%2F%2Fi.kinja-img.com%2Fgawker-media%2Fimage%2Fupload%2Fc_fill%2Cf_auto%2Cfl_progressive%2Cg_center%2Ch_675%2Cpg_1%2Cq_80%2Cw_1200%2Fy3dmfzz6ktqefakczlow.jpg&cfs=1&upscale=1&fallback=news_d_placeholder_publisher&_nc_hash=AQAApLwXk6n73twX" style="top:0px;" alt="" width="514" height="269" aria-label="photo of Journalist Allegedly Spied on Zoom Meetings of Rivals in Hilariously Dumb Ways image"></div>
                                    </div>
                                 </a>
                              </div>
                              <a class="_34js _8o63 _1kaa _34jt _34ju _2cpc" ajaxify="/feed/article_context/dialog/?share_id=10157963951502324&entry_type=news_feed_learn_more&trigger_log_id=bd3a8ea2-29fb-4ee2-b335-c27d26be3c85&ft_msg=mf_story_key.10157963951497324%3Atop_level_post_id.10157963951497324%3Atl_objid.10157963951497324%3Acontent_owner_id_new.675172323%3Athrowback_story_fbid.10157963951497324%3Astory_location.4%3Astory_attachment_style.share" href="#" rel="dialog-post" data-ft="{"tn":"-T"}" role="button" data-hover="tooltip" data-tooltip-content="Show more information about this link" data-tooltip-alignh="right" id="u_fetchstream_4_8"><i class="_34k2"></i></a>
                           </div>
                           <div class="_3ekx _29_4">
                              <div class="_6m3 _--6">
                                 <div class="_59tj _2iau">
                                    <div>
                                       <div class="_6lz _6mb _1t62 ellipsis">gizmodo.com</div>
                                       <div class=""></div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="_3n1k">
                                    <div class="mbs _6m6 _2cnj _5s6c"><a href="https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fgizmodo.com%2Fjournalist-allegedly-spied-on-zoom-meetings-of-rivals-i-1843125262%3Futm_campaign%3DGizmodo%26utm_content%26utm_medium%3DSocialMarketing%26utm_source%3Dfacebook%26fbclid%3DIwAR20yuiGAWmKatwN2MwmTXyBmz529Gwnb-h604xwyDNop7FiMX_hTwNDlE8&h=AT0XhG7ILFntZMvv9JimeFCtFMKTLchXKAVbYAyo7kl_dEkPltCRPbpLOroCd6pbCd0hzuD0Mvogr-cL0SEFRrLD0kkhcBkp6GrpjoTaYQwUSt7ReNTshqXkHGCYhAm6hb8qDKcZm3O0mEWUtgLM7_ALdSGyX9DyclB6OlIgsXg" rel="noopener nofollow" target="_blank" data-lynx-mode="asynclazy">Journalist Allegedly Spied on Zoom Meetings of Rivals in Hilariously Dumb Ways</a></div>
                                    <div class="_6m7 _3bt9">Financial Times reporter Mark Di Stefano allegedly spied on Zoom meetings at rival newspapers the Independent and the Evening Standard to get scoops on staff cuts and furloughs due to the coronavirus pandemic, according to a report from the UK’s Independent. And he did a comically bad job of cover...</div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                              <a href="https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fgizmodo.com%2Fjournalist-allegedly-spied-on-zoom-meetings-of-rivals-i-1843125262%3Futm_campaign%3DGizmodo%26utm_content%26utm_medium%3DSocialMarketing%26utm_source%3Dfacebook%26fbclid%3DIwAR2sRF3AjujE4KgspWs5ltmxgtABX46iAmdHGCVxDmWSzYu93cO_d1EMMfc&h=AT1duKty7qVugflB4dskMMBn6j1M0FJ-cneezEPDTrI6c2IcEKkCT1YZ6-8Bw2oad-n0gZZBFU5Mk-iTNkLo-up1anlYj_l_pIvZEVXz-2WPYAeQrILewicbiMd8Gj6ziLDys5z7PLZy2syfD1-HTufQ12efucyRp3hHa8mCcvGyPH1jtw" aria-label="Journalist Allegedly Spied on Zoom Meetings of Rivals in Hilariously Dumb Ways" aria-describedby="u_fetchstream_4_2" rel="noopener nofollow" tabindex="-1" target="_blank" class="_52c6" data-lynx-mode="asynclazy">
                                 <div class="accessible_elem" id="u_fetchstream_4_2">Financial Times reporter Mark Di Stefano allegedly spied on Zoom meetings at rival newspapers the Independent and the Evening Standard to get scoops on staff cuts and furloughs due to the coronavirus pandemic, according to a report from the UK’s Independent. And he did a comically bad job of cover...</div>
                              </a>
                           </div>
                        </span>
                     </div>
                     <div class="_42ef"><span class="_3c21"></span></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That link is in a `div` with four classes to choose from.

Comment: You might "get the wrong chunk of text" because there are multiple elements with `href` that start with "https://l.facebook". I don't see the "mbs" class used anywhere else in your sample, maybe using that and/or other classes could help narrow the selection to the element you want.

Comment: Yeah, I'm a bit concerned about using the random generated class names since they seem to change, hoping to use something more stable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the text e.g. by selecting a href starting with l.facebook that contains an element with the class name `accessible_elem` using `:has()` as this element contains the text.

```
 var copy = $(uCW).find('[href^="https://l.facebook"]:has(".accessible_elem")')
            .find(".accessible_elem").text();
```

Update: As mentioned as comment, this does not target the wanted text. Instead, it's possible to read out the aria-label attribute of this link as it contains the right text:

```
 var copy = $(ucw).find('[href^="https://l.facebook"]:has(".accessible_elem")').attr("aria-label");
```

Comment: Thanks, but accessible_elem actually doesn't have the right text in it, it just starts similarly, but it's much longer and more of a description than a title (in other examples, it can be wildly different) — I actually went down the accessible_elem rabbit hole for hours before realizing this. But the "has" trick is cool, I'll play with that.

Comment: @codi6 Just spotted the right text and adjusted my answer for it :)

Comment: Glad I was able to help again :)